# When is it OK to ask for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, moderators

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683224/how-to-really-treat-security-between-peers-in-webrtc) for moderator attention , but I got denied with the generic.

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I thought it was a decent question (not amazing), but it didn't belong on Stack Overflow.

> I don't mean to put too many moderator interventions, but I don't think this question really belongs on this site. It only partially hits on some of our processes, but in reality it should be in Programmers Stack Exchange where they discuss the correctness of usage / necessities of certain steps. This is not really a programming question when it comes down to it and is mentioned to be more geared towards a discussion. (I do not know where a more appropriate location may be.)

The first part was a mention because I know you can see history and I flagged a similar instance [here (almost identical IMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596362/android-external-usd-mount-omap-configurations) that was deemed helpful. I don't want to mark them too often because most often they are not needed to be dealt with by moderators.

I was going to vote to close because of it being off topic, but I thought it would be better to move it to another site like Programmers. This is not an option in the `Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` options.

[image]

So am I supposed to just flag to close and be at that or do I continue to flag for moderator attention?

Comment: Don't tickle the dragon's tail.

Comment: Flag to close and if you believe it really does belong somewhere else, let the OP know. Also mention to them to check the help center on that particular site before posting there

Comment: I'm not sure that question was high enough quality to migrate, could explain the decline

Comment: This seems like a good place to bring up my curiosity -- why are the migration flags so limited?

Comment: @codeMagic my fear in that case is if it does belong somewhere and it doesn't get closed fast enough here that user would be shot down and told not to duplicate post. But that makes sense. I have recommended it before as well. In fact in the other instance I did that just before I recommended it to be moved by a moderator.

Comment: @Trobbins [You can find many meta posts about that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=migrate+options)

Comment: @Trobbins because a) there's limited real estate on the screen and (more importantly) b) people are bad at migrating. They choose the wrong site and they migrate stuff that should be just closed.

Comment: _"When is it OK to ask for moderator attention?"_ Rarely to **never** regarding the subject.

Comment: >.> I feel like I'm missing something that should be slapping me in the face.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you're hinting that in reality I probably changed the question while asking it in a way?? Because now I feel like that's what happened, but Chris does provide what I basically need. It needs to be outstanding and on topic on the other site (while not being on topic here)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So am I supposed to just flag to close and be at that

Yes.

Moderators should only be made aware of content that you (that's the community "you", not you "you") can't deal with yourself. So for closing off topic questions you don't need a moderator. The community can do this itself.

For questions that you think should be migrated elsewhere not on the standard list, you better be sure that:

1. The question is outstanding.
2. The question is actually on topic on the site you want to migrate it to.

You've already admitted that you think this question is "not amazing" so it fails point 1 already. If the question passed both tests, *then* flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I'll keep these in mind. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: _that's the community "you", not you "you"_ was awesome to read... :)