# What do I do about a question that belongs on Ask Different?

Tags: support, flags, migration

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311873/el-capitan-xcode-7-1-not-letting-me-allow-enterprise-signing) that I believe belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). I was going to flag it as not belonging on this site, but I couldn't:

[image]

First, does it belong on Ask Different, and if it does, what should I do?

### Edit:

I looked at [When is it OK to ask for moderator attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300388/when-is-it-ok-to-ask-for-moderator-attention), but it doesn't answer my question because it never gets to the point of what to do to the question that is a great question; *then what?* It fits both criteria (I think, correct me if I am wrong), so what do I do now?

Comment: The duplicate does answer your question: if the question fits both criteria then flag for mod attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good issue to handle with a flag because it's not an issue that only moderators can handle (and the question shouldn't actually be closed, as I explain below).

[At 3,000 reputation, users can vote to close questions without raising a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Five such votes will close the question without moderator intervention. Once you reach that reputation level, *if the question is off-topic*, it would be appropriate to cast an "off-topic" close vote using either this reason

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

or a custom explanation referencing Ask Different.

Here, however, it's not appropriate to flag it or close-vote it. This is a question about signing with Xcode, which is clearly relevant to programming and on-topic for Stack Overflow. So, in this case, the appropriate action is to do nothing; it's a good question.