# Flag for asking about product support?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, declined-flags

I recently flagged a question asking about when support will end for a product. I thought about flagging as off topic due to asking for offsite resources but i thought it didn't quite fit, so I used a custom flag with the message:

> The question asks about support length for a product.

I recently found out it was declined with the following message:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?.

Did I miss a flag somewhere? Or isn't there a flag asking about product support?

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815817/any-plans-for-angular-team-to-end-support-for-ie-11).

Comment: The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52815817/timeline) doesn't show a review. You have casted a custom moderator flag. You should have flagged as "Should be closed"

Comment: Also related: [When is it OK to ask for moderator attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300388/when-is-it-ok-to-ask-for-moderator-attention).

Comment: see also: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Answer (score 8):

For people without enough rep to cast close votes, the proper way to flag a customer support question is *Should be closed* -> *Off-topic* -> *Blatantly off-topic*. That reason is valid for all non-standard off-topic reasons, it doesn't really have to be blatantly off-topic.

For people with enough rep to cast close votes, it's *Off topic* -> *Other*, with an explanation that it's customer support and why that's off-topic.

Comment: i did that, my question was why was my custom flag declined and why was i told to use a standard flag when none seem appropriate?

Comment: No, you didn't, because that message is only for mod flags, not off-topic flags. You flagged _In need of moderator intervention_, and that's not appropriate for questions that are just off-topic.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon No, you didn't do "that". The "other" Erik mentions is not yet available to you, since you have less than 3k rep. You should have chosen "blatanty off-topic".

Comment: but "blatanty off-topic" wasnt suitable, it didnt fit the best

Comment: Well, it wasn't in need of moderator intervention, because moderators don't handle questions that should be closed, the community does. As I've stated in my answer, the _blatantly off-topic_ flag is valid for all non-standard off-topic reasons.